# keep the UISearchBarDisplayController on Top of tableview

Tags: uitableview, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

i'm trying to keep the UISearchBarDisplayController on top of UItableview in swift 
i tried this code (which i convert from objectC to swift) but no luck:

```
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
//        
        var searchBar: UISearchBar  = (self.searchDisplayController?.searchBar)!
//
        var rect = searchBar.frame

        self.searchDisplayController?.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, max(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y), rect.width, rect.height);
    }
```

the search bar still scroll with tableview when i scroll the table. Does anyone can help me to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found that i have to make a new view controller , add a tableview and add a searchBar outside of the tableview. and the search bar won't scroll with the tableview

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 2.1, iOS 9.2.1 and Xcode 7.2**

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        /* Search controller parameters */
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self  // This protocol allows your class to be informed as text changes within the UISearchBar.
            searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false  // In this instance,using current view to show the results, so do not want to dim current view.
            definesPresentationContext = true   // ensure that the search bar does not remain on the screen if the user navigates to another view controller while the UISearchController is active.

            let tableHeaderView: UIView = UIView.init(frame: searchController.searchBar.frame)
            tableHeaderView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView

        }
        override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
           let searchBar:UISearchBar = searchController.searchBar
           var searchBarFrame:CGRect = searchBar.frame
           if searchController.active {
              searchBarFrame.origin.y = 10
           }
           else {
             searchBarFrame.origin.y = max(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top)

           }
           searchController.searchBar.frame = searchBarFrame
       }
```

Comment: This will keep the search bar at the top when scrolling. But if I scroll and try to tap the search bar, to activate the search bar, when there is a table view cell under the search bar, it will select the tableViewCell instead of the search bar.